# Error when Installing TensorFlow with PipEnv

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pipenv

I am trying to install TensorFlow using pipenv, however installation is always failing.

I am using the Command Prompt on Windows 7.

I have tried the below Pipfile as well as manually specifying tensorflow = "==1.11.0", but nothing seems to be working.

This is my current Pipfile:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
requests = "*"
pandas = "*"
scipy = "*"
seaborn = "*"
scikit-learn = "*"
tensorflow = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.6"
```

The error I receive (after running `pipenv install`) is:

```
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (a4b797)...
An error occurred while installing tensorflow==1.12.0 --hash=.....
.....! Will try again.

.....

[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ['Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.12.0 .....']
ERROR: ERROR: Package installation failed...
```

If anyone can help me that would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had a 32 bit version of Python installed.  Tensorflow requires a 64 bit version.

After re-installing, I also needed to remove the old pipenv via `pipenv --rm`.